# Has anyone tried to use Snowflake as a Grafana datasource?

Tags: grafana, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm currently trying to figure out if there is any proper way to visualize the data from Snowflake DWH in Grafana.

What I've found during my "googling" is:

1. [Question in the local community forum](https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00009R7EfYSAV/anyone-tried-jdbc-connection-to-grafana-monitoring-and-dashboarding-for-dashboarding-snowflake-table-data-granafa-gui-doesnt-have-snowflake-as-provided-data-source-any-pointers-on-this)

> I did find more information on Prometheus exporters
>
> - https://github.com/free/sql_exporter
> - https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/exporters/Looks like
> - sql_exporter work with Snowflake Go driver:
> - https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/go-driver.html
> - http://www.tosnowflake.com/ -links to Tografana
> - https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/11587 - no plugin 2018

2. The solution to [schedule the data polling by Logstash](https://medium.com/@izekchen/pull-data-from-snowflake-with-logstash-b1120c812d99) and then ship the data to Elasticsearch where we can query the data in Grafana.

Both of these resources don't seem reassuring and I'm wondering if there is any straightforward way to connect them together.

Answer (score 6):

Now there is a free data source plugin provided by Michelin
https://github.com/michelin/snowflake-grafana-datasource

Answer (score 4):

To the question: "if there is any proper way to visualize the data from Snowflake DWH in Grafana", the answer is yes.

AndrewM answered:

> Grafana recently released a Snowflake plugin on their website: https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/grafana-snowflake-datasource

This means you won't need to use Prometheus, nor an exporter, nor Logstash. Just connect Snowflake directly to Grafana.

(I'm not sure why Andrew's answer was deleted by a mod, but this is the correct answer to the question)

Note that to get access to the official Grafana plugin for Snowflake, you'll need to be a customer of their Enterprise plan.

Comment: But you would need Grafana Enterprise subscription to use this plugin

Comment: if you are paying to use snowflake, you should be able to afford to pay for Grafana.